# Share code between two repos that require different versions of node

Tags: yarnpkg, vercel, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo with this dependency tree:

```
/root
  package.json
  /packages
    /api <--- requires node v16.x because of a critical dependency
      package.json
    /ui  <--- requires node v14.x because Vercel does not yet support v16.x
      package.json
    /shared <--- shared code between both /ui and /api
      package.json
```

I'm unable to deploy the `/ui` package on Vercel because it complains of about the dependency under `/api` that requires v16.

Is there a way to configure yarn workspaces such the offending dependency can be ignored when building `/ui`, or is my only option to eject from yarn workspaces and find some other way to share the `/shared` code?

---

**Another way of asking the question:**
I have repo A which must run on node 16, and repo B which must run on node 14. How can I share code between the two repos? Yarn workspaces isn't working for me because it forces all packages to conform to a single node version.

Comment: Have you tried to make node a dependency? It theoretically should work. If that fails I would look into `asdf`.

Comment: @Dominik thanks for the reply - the problem isn't choosing the correct version of node at build time, it's that the `/ui` build fails despite building in the correct v14 of node, because the offending dependency in `/api` requires v16 and conflicts. I need a way for that one particular dependency to be included when building `/api`, but ignored/excluded when building `/ui` - does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would a dependency you don't need build? You would have had to included it in `/ui` somewhere right? If I understand the issue correctly you need to split up `/shared` into separate packages so they don't conflict with node.

Comment: Any npm package can specify a minimum version of node. The offending package that `/api` depends on requires node v16. But because the repo is setup with yarn workspaces, when I yarn install `/ui` with node v14, it still complains about the offending package

Comment: So your question is simply: how can I use a dependency hat requires node 16 when I can only run node 14?

Comment: Almost - the exact dimension I'm trying to solve is this:

> "Is there a way to configure yarn workspaces such the offending dependency can be ignored when building /ui, or is my only option to eject from yarn workspaces and find some other way to share the /shared code?"

Comment: **Another way of asking the question:** 
I have repo A which must run on node 16, and repo B which must run on node 14. How can I share code between the two repos? Yarn workspaces isn't working for me because it forces all packages to conform to a single node version.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up ejecting `/ui` from yarn workspaces, and continuing to share code by just importing the files from outside of the package's root directory.

I had a lot of file includes that utilized the following convention because of yarn workspaces:

```js
import { someFunc } from '@project/shared/someFile'
```

Quite elegantly, I was able to continue sharing code without having to change that syntax at all - by simply updating `jsconfig.json` to simulate yarn workspaces:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@project/shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
    }
  }
}
```